# Manual TCP connection using WiFi ESP8266 module mistyped command

Tags: serial, wifi, esp8266

The command is working fine if I type it directly to the serial interface

```
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","192.168.1.5",1647
```

But if I want to make it automatic and send it whenever I want from inside the code is not working at all.

Used this but it's not working (Serial1 is from the hardware sp)

```
Serial1.println("AT+CIPSTART="TCP","192.168.1.5",1647")
```

Any way to arrange the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape your quotes:

```
Serial1.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"192.168.1.5\",1647");
```

Comment: Man that was fast! Thanks Majenko it worked perfectly!